# Connecting to remote host via putty

Tags: ssh, putty, x11

I am getting the following error when i try to connect to a remote host.

```
Can't connect to X11 Windows server using "0:0" as the value of the display variable.
```

How do i get past it?

Other info:

1. I am running a windows machine and the host is unix based.
2. I have Xming installed.
3. I have given the display command as export DISPLAY=0:0
4. I have checked X11 option in SSH.

Comment: Try not to export the DISPLAY option. It should be set automatically by ssh when X11 forwarding is turned on.

Comment: Did you verify x11 forwarding is enabled in your ssh server config?

Answer (score 1):

Don't attempt to set the `DISPLAY` environment variable on the remote host. This is set automatically by ssh and should not be changed.

Answer (score 1):

X11 forwarding will work if the following conditions are met:

- X server installed locally
- X11 forwarding checked in Putty (or -X option of ssh at the command line)
- X11 forwarding enabled in the server config (/etc/ssh/sshd_config)
- package providing the xauth binary installed on the remote machine